# Positioning for drop down menu items

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm VERY new to coding/jQuery and I'm just trying to figure out why my drop down menu isn't positioning correctly. The items that are supposed to "drop down", end up on the left side of the page. Here is my page here: https://jsfiddle.net/apinck/sco9wx26/

Something must be up with my CSS, I'm guessing?

```
li {
list-style-type: none;
display:inline;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-size: 21px;
}
ul {
text-align:center;
}
.topmenu {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
}
.submenu {
display: none;
width: 150px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You alignment is due to the position property and you display property on the li-elements in the submenu.

**submenu add position: absolute**

```
.submenu {
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    left:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

**create submenu li**

```
.submenu li {
    display:block;
    font-size:0.8em;
}
```

To anchor the submenu to the topmenu, you must add a position relative

```
.topmenu {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position:relative;
}
```

To see the thing working see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sco9wx26/1/

**edit >>**

I see "left on the page". By omitting the position:relative; on your topmenu, the submenu will position itself on the left of the page. By doing this, the positioning takes place to the first parent that has the position property set.

Hope that helps you at least on the positioning problem.